# how to make spring 3.1 and hibernate 4.1.x available with all portlet without cause conflict with ROOT liferay

Tags: spring, hibernate, liferay, portlet, spring-portlet-mvc

I have multiple portlets that using the same frameworks and I used to deploy these dependencies with each portlet which cause PermGen issue especially when I do deploy/undeploy for the portlet.

Sometimes this issue appeared suddenly even without deploy/undeploy.

I'm thinking to move these dependencies to tomcat level but the problem it will conflict with the version liferay using it.

Here are my JVM params:

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -Dorg.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.ENABLE_CLEAR_REFERENCES=false -Duser.timezone=GMT -Djruby.min.runtimes=1 -Djruby.max.runtimes=3 -Djruby.runtime=1 -XX:NewSize=700m -XX:MaxNewSize=700m -Xms2048m -Xms2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m  -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:SurvivorRatio=10 -XX:ParallelGCThreads=8"
```

any other recommended solutions?

Comment: Do you use Maven? Have you tried incresing the max PermGen of your Liferay instance?

Comment: You don't give the current values you have for PermGen - if it's reasonable: Just increase it. That's what you'll typically have to do if you're running out of PermGen memory. After all, that sort of memory is typically never garbage-collected. If you constantly redeploy but leak permgen memory, you might have to restart the server after a few redeployments.

Answer (score 0):

Liferay 6.1 uses Spring 3.0.7 in its root portlet.

If you configure these as dependencies in the `portal-dependency-jars` in `liferay-plugin-package.properties`, these will be copied into your portlet, so it is much like including them on your own.  Of course, any library you include in your portlet will increase your use of PermGen space.

Placing different Spring and Hibernate libraries in Tomcat may cause class loading issues.  As Hibernate 4.x doesn't really play well with Spring earlier than 3.1, you have a bit of a problem.  You could try upgrading the Spring inside the root portlet.  I never got that to work, personally.

I would increase the PermGen space and put the libraries in your portlet.  Also, in your war, you might want to put this in `META-INF/context.xml` if you are using Tomcat.

```
<Context>
    <Loader loaderClass="com.liferay.support.tomcat.loader.PortalClassLoader" />
</Context>
```

This may fix some classloading issues.  In some cases it doesn't make any difference, but if you're using separate libraries, it may be important.

Comment: I think should think seriously in downgrade our portlets  from spring 3.1 to spring 3.0.6 and the same thing in hibernate since no way to make shared library for multiple portlets in tomcat if you want to use shared loader. all the portlet will see this library and will cause conflict issue with ROOT Portlet